# Hair particles are thinner when rendered in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, particles, hair

So I was making some grass for my low poly scene in blender, but the hair particles don't have the same thickness in the final render as opposed to the thickness in the viewport render. In the final render they look very thin, instead of looking thicker as I made them to be.

The final render of the scene where the grass is very thin:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGgN7.png]

The viewport render of my scene where the grass is how it is supoosed to look:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nd4Aj.png]

Comment: it's probably due to the fact that a render tapers the tip.  I can't recall the values, but let's say the base is 1, and the tip is 0.2  so try setting your particles to a uniform thickness, where the tip has the same thickness as the base.

Comment: @Doyousketch2 Thanks, you were correct. Making the value of the tip the same as the base does yield the result in the viewport render.

Comment: have you got the particle amount set the same for eevee as cycles?